# How to save image on fabric canvas toSVG?

Tags: image, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I'm trying to save fabric canvas in SVG. But if I have an image on canvas it will be stored as a path to image on web server. And if i want to download canvas as svg file image will be lost.
Also, i've tried to store image as base64, but it lose quality.

It's result image tag in downloaded SVG

```
<image xlink:href="https://localhost:44303/Files/instagram-256.png" x="-100" y="-100" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="200" height="200" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
```

Is there some way to save convas with image in SVG and download it in high quality?

Comment: Why would you loose quality during the base64 conversion?

Comment: I don't know, i used canvas conversion and image was damaged. But now  I use file reader and everything is fine